# Is there a more efficient way to reset the contents of cells that have been edited in a JTable back to what they previously were

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've tried tackling this problem by creating 2 separate data arrays, containing the same information. One of these data arrays(tableData) is used in the constructor for a JTable, while the other(oldTableData) is used for changing values in the cells back to their original value when the application first ran. I need the second data array, as the first data array automatically updates everytime I change a value in a cell in the table, is it possible to disable this feature of a JTable?

I need this feature to be used when the cancel button is clicked while editing cells in the table, since the cancel button should undo all changes made while editing cells. Here's my implementation for the cancel button so far:

```
if(e.getSource().equals(cancelMenuButton)) {
        //prints set of edited cells
        System.out.println("edited cells: "+editedCells);

        ///once cancel button is clicked, disable both submit and cancel, as we are out of edit mode
        cancelMenuButton.setEnabled(false);
        submitMenuButton.setEnabled(false);

        //reset values in table
        Iterator<Point> iterator = editedCells.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Point point = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Value at "+point.x+", "+point.y+": "+table.getValueAt(point.y, point.x));
            System.out.println("Old value at "+point.x+", "+point.y+": "+oldTableData[point.y][point.x]);

            table.setValueAt(oldTableData[point.y][point.x], point.y, point.x);
        }

        editedCells.clear();

        //cancel cell editing
        CellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor();
        if(cellEditor != null) {
            if(cellEditor.getCellEditorValue() != null) {
                cellEditor.stopCellEditing();
            } else {
                cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is whether or not there is an easier way to do this, one which doesn't require creating two identical data arrays. Thank you.

Comment: whats your code for setValueAt, for better help soomer post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is an easier way to do this,

This is probably the easiest way to do this. You can just create a new TableModel using this data and reset the model of the table.

However the problem is that you need two copies of the data.

> one which doesn't require creating two identical data arrays.

Then you would need to track when the data in a cell is changed.

So you could keep a `HashMap` where the key is the row/column and the data is the original value. So on a "Cancel" you would just iterate through the `HashMap` and restore the data for each key found in the Map.

You can use the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) to listen for changes to the TableModel. Then whenever an event is generated you would check the row/column of the HashMap to see if it has a value. If not, you would save the original value.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to disable the first data array from changing once a cell is edited, so I could just collect the original values from the data array. I think I'll just stick with the two array. Thank you for your help.